# Rectangle coordinates drawn on Image in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am trying to get following usecase implemented in Xamarin forms
(Using with SFImageEditor from syncfusion but can try if other options)

1. Display an image in editor.
2. Display an initial rectangle.
3. User resizes the rectangle to best fit and clicks "go".
4. Need to Capture the coordinates of this rectangle in reference to the image.
5. Send the image and rectangle coordinates for further processing.

Can someone pls provide guidance on step 4 for identifying the coordinates of the rectangle.
(X Y height width) or (coordinates of 4 corners). Either format is fine.
Appreciate your help.

code to set SFImageEditor in Xamarin.Forms with Syncfusion.

Xaml code

```
<imageeditor:SfImageEditor   x:Name="present_image"     >
    <imageeditor:SfImageEditor.ToolbarSettings>
       <imageeditor:ToolbarSettings IsVisible="True"   />
    </imageeditor:SfImageEditor.ToolbarSettings>
</imageeditor:SfImageEditor>
```

code behind

```
public ImgEditPage( )
{
    InitializeComponent();          
    var origImage = ImageSource.FromUri(
            new Uri("https://xxx.xx/xxxxxx.jpg")); ;
    present_image.Source = origImage; 
}
```

This will open up the image in an editor window, The editor allows to draw a rectangle object.
User can click the button to draw rectangle I want to get the coordinates of the rectangle drawn by user.

Comment: without knowing the details of how you implement this, there is no way to give you any specific guidance on a specific step.  If you already plan on using SF, then that will probably be a huge factor.  Otherwise I would suggest using SkiaSharp

Comment: syncfusion has sfImageEditor component.

Comment: There seems no such api in SfImageEditor that you can get the rectangle coordinates drawn on Image.

Answer (score 0):

We would like to let you know that the you can get the coordinates of the rectangle added on an image by using the Bounds property. On selecting a shape, ItemSelected event will be triggered. From this, you will get settings of selected shape with Bounds property. The value of the Bounds will be in percentage, the value of the shape frame should fall between 0 and 100. For more information, please refer the below link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/8880/how-to-show-dimension-of-shapes-while-resizing

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/image-editor/shapes#pensettings

You can get the actual bounds of the image rendered in SfImageEditor control using the property ActualImageRenderedBounds.

You can get the original image size by using the property of OriginalImageSize.